# How to recognize when a forever button is released in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

Is there a way for the code in a forever button to recognize that the button was released? I would like to terminate the button's operations cleanly when the user wants it to stop.

I realize that when a forever button is released, its code completes, but that doesn't tell me whether it will repeat again.

Thanks.

Comment: not quite sure what you're asking here - what is 'it' that might repeat again? If the go button is pressed, it will again call the go procedure (assuming following convention about procedure names) until the button is released or a stop condition is satisfied.

Comment: I want to be able to test in my program whether a repeating go button has been released so that I can end the go procedure with special actions in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short: no, there is no way to do this.

Comment: Too bad! It would be a useful feature.